# Limit law of real-valued independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be real-valued independent r.vs, each of whose limit law is $X$ and Y, resp.

i.e $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ and $Y_n \overset{d}{\to} Y$ for some r.vs $X$ and $Y$.

Then, are $X$ and $Y$ independent as well?

I don't think it holds, but with the lemma below, I make it, which makes me surprised.

> **Lemma.** $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ are independent if and only if
>   $$ \Bbb{E}[ f_{1}(X_{1})\cdots f_{n}(X_{n}) ] = \Bbb{E} f_{1}(X_{1}) \cdots \Bbb{E} f_{n}(X_{n})$$
>   for any bounded continuous functions $f_{1}, \cdots, f_{n}$.

Thus, I wonder if there exists such result.

Anyone, any comments would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't the $f_i$'s have to be Borel-measurable as well? In any case, I don't think this lemma can directly help you. No idea for the actual question but am curious haha

Comment: each $f_i$ is mapping from $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Thus, I think the continuity of $f_i$ implies measurability.

Comment: Beware! You could apply the lemma if you had convergence in distribution for the **pair** $(X_n,Y_n)$ to $(X,Y)$.

Comment: @Simeon, Oh, thanks for notice.

Comment: Oh right. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545159/continuity-implies-borel-measurability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Then, are $X$ and $Y$ independent as well?

Of course not, consider some nondegenerate random variable $X$, independent sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ i.i.d. distributed like $X$, and $Y=X$.

How you planned to apply the lemma is a mystery.

Comment: Oh, you right. Thank you so much.

Comment: Then, is the lemma true? I wonder where my proof makes a problem.

Comment: Yes the lemma is true but "how you planned to apply" it to prove a false result "is a mystery".

Comment: Ok, after double-checking my "false" proof, I'm going to decide whether I post it or not.

Comment: I found where I made a idiotic logic. Thanks, Did. p.s. I got help from you several times, and I really appreciate every time.

Comment: You are welcome. What was the faulty step?

Comment: I would like to know as well @inmybrain

Comment: @BCLC Never mind, I made a wrong step.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I should leave this as a comment but I don't have enough points. I assume that $\forall (m,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, $X_n \perp Y_m$.</strike>

<strike>You can use the the properties of the characteristic function of the couple $(X_n, Y_m)$ and Levy's continuity theorem. (I suggest working with the characteristic function because it is continuous, so it's neat not to worry about treating discontinuity points).</strike>

Comment: Then, do you mean the claim holds?

Comment: Sorry. Yes it's a true statement.

Comment: Ok, thanks for comment! : )

Comment: How do you plan to apply Lévy's continuity theorem?

Comment: Nvm. Im an idiot.

Comment: He can pick independent copies of $X$ and $Y$, or maybe he can get a cvg in probability. Sunday morning is no excuse for what I wrote.