# What can we say about continuity by knowing Borel-Measurability?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I've seen in multiple posts (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545159/continuity-implies-borel-measurability), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960483/if-x-is-a-borel-set-and-f-has-countably-many-discontinuities-prove-that-f?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369268/a-function-with-countable-discontinuities-is-borel-measurable)) on how continuity properties of functions imply Borel-Measurability, in a very natural way relating the topological definition of continuity with the definition of Borel-Measurability itself. I'm wondering if everyone knows about results in the opposite direction: *what can we say about continuity properties (e.g. continuous, almost surely continuous, countably-discontinuous, or even other definitions of continuity such as equicontinuity, and so on) by knowing that a function is Borel Measurable?*

Comment: Not so much I am afraid. Very weird functions can still be Borel measurable.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if any additional conditions would help? Such being bounded, having compact support, and so on?@drhab

Comment: Not really. I never dived into this material because it looked so hopeless :-).

Comment: note that the Dirichlet function is nowhere continuous and Borel measurable. I dont think we can say something useful because if we reject the axiom of choice then any function will be Borel measurable

Comment: @Masacroso that is true! As drhab said, it seems pretty much hopeless without constraining assumptions. Thanks y'all